# Symfony2 Form : Select an entity or add a new one

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an `order` and a `client` entity.

I am wondering if it's possible with the actual Symfony2 form system to create an order form which will allow to:

1. Select several clients from a dropdown (mix of `collection` and `entity` form type)
2. And to create new clients on the fly (the default way for the `collection` type) if not in the dropdown list.

I've seen some way to do it by creating multiple forms in the same page, but this is not the way I would like to achieve it.

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem which may lead to your resolution:

I have a Category and Item relationship (Many-to-One) and I wanted to either select an existing item or create a new item.

In my Form class:

```
    $builder->add('item', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Item',
        'class' => 'ExampleItemBundle:Item',
    ));

    $builder->add('itemNew', new EmbedItemForm(), array(
        'required' => FALSE,
        'mapped' => FALSE,
        'property_path' => 'item',
    ));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (!empty($data['itemNew']['name'])) {
            $form->remove('item');

            $form->add('itemNew', new EmbedItemForm(), array(
                'required' => TRUE,
                'mapped' => TRUE,
                'property_path' => 'item',
            ));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Need to use EmbedItemForm::class as type is string|null in add method since symfony 3 (maybe 2.?).

Comment: This works well for me. I just modified it so I didn't have to use two different form keys. Before the listener I use my custom form type. In the listener I just check if(is_numeric($data['item']) then I remove the form and add a EntityType form.

Comment: @patrick I'm using the exact same example but for some reason I'm getting the error "this form should not contain extra fields". I'm sure the eventListener got called to remove / add the fields correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can map two fields in a form to the same property using the `property_path` option. Then, using form events, use the submitted data to make a decision and modify the form so that only one of the fields has a `mapped` option that is `true`.

Comment: I am really interested in this solution, could you provide detailed example?

Comment: @antony, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @SteeveDroz I answered this nearly 2 years ago. I think the info you require is all in here 
https://knpuniversity.com/blog/property_path and http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood, you want to create and store new clients in a Form "on fly", at the moment. I think that you have to do that using JavaScript and set an additional action in your controller.

1. *JS* -> Capture the event to add new client to you database (i.e. "Add new" button click event)
2. *JS* ->  Inside this event, call via AJAX to your controller with the values of new client. (Using [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/) is easy to do)
3. *Symfony2* -> Inside your new action, store the new client in your database.
4. *JS* -> OnSuccess event, in your AJAX call, add the new Client to your DropDownBox
   (ddb.append(new element tag)

Just doing that you have your new client stored in the database and added to your dropdownbox

Comment: The idea was to create a dropdown showing the existing clients, but also the ability to create a new client (if not present on the list) in the same form. And I decided indeed to use some js to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

For my part i had the same kind of problem and i resolved it by creating 2 attribute in my `formType`;

For example, for you it would be:

```
customer->entity
new_customer-> collection
```

In your order entity file you will have to add 3 methods (getter, setter, and remover) getter and remover don't do anything but setter should call the `setCustomer(c)`

I'm not sure if it is the best way but it's the only way I figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

The `collection` Form type allows to add and delete on the fly with `allow_add` and `allow_delete` attribute.

More informations by following these 2 links :

- [Official collection form field type reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)
- [Cookbook about add and delete on the fly with collection type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#cookbook-form-collections-new-prototype)

If you don't like to get supplementary forms on the same page, you can integrate them in dialog boxes... But you definitely need a form to create new items...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the `collection` type. But I have the feeling that I can either add and delete existing clients, or add and delete new clients, but not add an existing client and create a new one (for example) in the same form. Am i wrong ? I hope it's clear.

Comment: I guess you have to diferrenciate 'Add an existing client' from 'Add a new client' as forms must be different.

Comment: I believe that doesn't answers the original question, which to me was : is there an elegant way to add either existing or new objects to a collection ? I don't understand why this answer was accepted.