# Select existing entity or create a new one

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've read [Symfony 2 Entity field type with select and/or add new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682494/symfony-2-entity-field-type-with-select-and-or-add-new) and this [Symfony2 Form : Select an entity or add a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194693/symfony2-form-select-an-entity-or-add-a-new-one) but those topics didn't solve what I want.

I want for user to choose from existing entities but if he wants to, should be able to create a new one after clicking on a button ( which will render form ). I know how to render entities in select, I know how to render field which allows user to create few new entities ( collection ) but I don't know how to render both of them together.

right now I have select:

```
->add('place', 'entity', array(
        'required' => false,
        'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Place',
))
```

but as I said - I want to allow user to add new entity if he wants to. I was trying with collection:

```
->add('place', 'collection', array(            
    'required' => false,
    'data' => [new Place()],
    'type' => new \MyBundle\Form\Place\PlaceType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'options' => array( 'label' => false),
))
```

but that only allowed user to create new entities, not to select from existing ones...

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be able to add a new entity and select an existing one i'd suggest you take a look at form events.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html